# errors implementing a shell in C

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am trying to implement a basic shell in c. But I am running into a problem where I print the contents of the char array and it only prints out the first command of what I type. So for example if I typed "ls -l" it would only print out "ls". However this confuses me since when I type out ls -l when I run the shell it executes the right command and shows the permissions for every file. Now when I do "rm -f /path/to/file" it does not remove it. Also if i do "cd /path" it acts like it does not see the 2nd argument(path). I cant figure out what is going on. Any insight?

```
while (1) {
            /* Print the command prompt */
            printf("prompt> ");
            fgets(input, 1024, stdin);

            // get first token
            args[i++] = strtok(input, " \n");

            while((args[i++] = strtok(NULL, " \n")) != NULL);
            args[i] = NULL;

            printf("%s\n", *args);



        if(strcmp(*args, "exit") == 0)
            exit(1);

        else{
            int pid = fork();
            if(pid == 0){
                execvp(args[0], args);

    else waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);


        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Is this an assignment or you are trying to build a real shell? In the second case, you should really learn about parser generators and avoid hand-coding parsers unless you have a compelling reason to do so. It's  a painful and error-prone task, as recent episodes demonstrate.

Comment: Why would you expect a single invocation of `printf("%s\n", *args)` to print more than one string?

Comment: probably `algol 68` is more popular than `C` when it comes to shells and command line environments in general, `C` is not that popular among this family of software . Implementing an usable, not trivial shell, must be a long painful task for a very little gain .

Comment: @user2485710, fully agreed that implementing a nontrivial shell (as opposed to the trivial subset frequently given as an assignment by lazy CS professors) is difficult to do in a complete and correct manner. Strongly disagreed that C is an unpopular choice of implementation language for the task.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy can you name shells implemented in `C` ? maybe `csh` ?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Expecting shell `printf` behaviour of consuming all arguments one-at-a-time is the most charitable theory I've got for that.

Comment: And I expect this is the same assignment that a number of other people have been asking about over the past week or two (at least four or five questions that I've seen).

Comment: @user2485710, ash, dash, bash, zsh. And, for that matter, Korn and heirloom Bourne as well. I almost wonder if the question was deliberately trolling; it's hard to find a major shell *not* written in C.

Comment: this for an assignment. I think I found out why I am getting weird results. I think I am not resetting the arguments array after every command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
args[i++] = strtok(input, " \n");

        while((args[i++] = strtok(NULL, " \n")) != NULL);
        args[i] = NULL;
```

args is initialized at the start of the program, since this is shell program (assuming no argument is passed while executing this program) only exec is named is passed at the start of the program so argc=1 and args[0] = "your exec name".args and argc are stored on the stack before the program is executed.
So when you are doing args[i++] it is an illegal operation,wonder why program wasn't terminated.
Try parse the arguments/tokens in a pre-allocated or dynamic buffer.